# ListAdapter - SimpleAdapter whit a Class how make

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a List of class Recipe:

```
List<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList<Recipe>();
```

and the class whit attributes basics:

```
 public class Recipe {
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public String time;
...
```

Im try put this in SimpleAdapter but Android Studio acuses error when i make this:

```
 ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
ResultActivity.this,
recipeList,R.layout.list_item,
new String[] {"id","name","time"},
new int[] { R.id.id,R.id.name,R.id.time  }
                    );
```

Im see some examples transforming this in Map but have how make directly whit the class how parameter, thanks much this save my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your data mapping this way:

```
    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> mapData = 
        new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    for (Recipe recipe : recipeList) {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("id", String.valueOf(recipe.id));
        map.put("name", recipe.name);
        map.put("time", recipe.time);

        mapData.add(map);

    }
```

and this should work:

```
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(ResultActivity.this, mapData,
        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "id", "name", "time" },
        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.time });
```